# GCD blocking samplePing's response

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am pinging all the avaialable IPS within range on the wifi network like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < Range; i++) {
    [SimplePingHelper ping:strIps[i]];
}
```

As one can imagine this activity takes quite a long time and as such I'd like to run it in the background. The snippet above is a part of a larger method that I'll post below. I've done multiple debugger sessions and one thing I noticed is that when I call the scan method (see below), samplePing (straight from apple) does not reach

```
static void HostResolveCallback(CFHostRef theHost, 
                                CFHostInfoType typeInfo, 
                                const CFStreamError *error, 
                                void *info)
```

When this method is not reached the arp table is not loaded and my app no longer works.

Here is how I invoke the GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 ), ^{
    [self scanWifi];
});
```

Here is the scanWifi Method:

```
-(void)scanWifi{
    WifiInfo *wi = [[WifiInfo alloc] init];
    NSString *phoneIp = [wi getIPAddress:true];
    NSString *maxIp = [wi getBroadcastIp:phoneIp];
    NSString *minIp = [wi getMinIp:phoneIp];

    unsigned long ULmaxIp = [wi StrIp2UnsignedLong:maxIp];
    unsigned long ULminIp = [wi StrIp2UnsignedLong:minIp];
    ULmaxIp --;
    ULminIp ++;

    unsigned long iterateIp = ULminIp;
    unsigned long Range = ULmaxIp - ULminIp;


    NSString *strIps [Range];

    for (int i = 0; i < Range; i++) {
        strIps[i] = [wi unsignedInt2StrIp:iterateIp];
        iterateIp ++;
    }


    for (int i=0; i < Range; i++) {
        //I am using a simplePingHelper to handle management of the SamplePing
        [SimplePingHelper ping:strIps[i]];
    }

    ip2mac *i2m = [[ip2mac alloc] init];


    for (int i = 0; i < Range; i++) {
        //convert the ip to a char string
        char *chIp = (char *)[strIps[i] UTF8String];
        //use the char string to look into arp table
        NSString *mac = [[i2m Stip2mac:chIp]uppercaseString];

        //this is the mac prefix I want
        if([mac hasPrefix:@"60:CB:FB"]) {

            //check device exists
            if ([self deviceExist]) {
                //update device that already exists in core data
                [self updateToCoreData:@"AirScapeFan" :strIps[i] :mac :@"ssid"];
            }else{
                //add new device to core data
                [self saveToCoreData:@"AirScapeFan" :strIps[i] :mac :@"ssid"];
            }
            //Method to call up all entries in core data and print them
            [self printFromCoreData];
        }        
    }
}
```

Just for kicks: Here is my slightly modified SimplePingHelper code:

```
//
//  SimplePingHelper.m
//  PingTester
//
//  Created by Chris Hulbert on 18/01/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SimplePingHelper.h"

@interface SimplePingHelper()

@property(nonatomic,retain) SimplePing* simplePing;

- (id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)address;
- (void)go;

@end

@implementation SimplePingHelper
@synthesize simplePing;

#pragma mark - Run it

// Pings the address, and calls the selector when done. Selector must take a NSnumber which is a bool for success
+ (void)ping:(NSString*)address {
    // The helper retains itself through the timeout function
    [[[SimplePingHelper alloc] initWithAddress:address] go];
}

#pragma mark - Init/dealloc

- (void)dealloc {
    self.simplePing = nil;
}

- (id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)address {
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.simplePing = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:address];
        self.simplePing.delegate = self;
  }
 return self;
}

#pragma mark - Go

- (void)go {
    [self.simplePing start];
    [self performSelector:@selector(endTime) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; // This timeout is what retains the ping helper
}

#pragma mark - Finishing and timing out

// Called on success or failure to clean up
- (void)killPing {
   [self.simplePing stop]; // In case, higher up the call stack, this got called by the simpleping object itself
   self.simplePing = nil;
}

- (void)successPing {
    [self killPing];

}

- (void)failPing:(NSString*)reason {
    [self killPing];
}

// Called 1s after ping start, to check if it timed out
- (void)endTime {
    if (self.simplePing) { // If it hasn't already been killed, then it's timed out
        [self failPing:@"timeout"];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Pinger delegate

// When the pinger starts, send the ping immediately
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address {
     [self.simplePing sendPingWithData:nil];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self failPing:@"didFailWithError"];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error {
    // Eg they're not connected to any network
    [self failPing:@"didFailToSendPacket"];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet {
    [self successPing];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came with one of the delegates in the library that I modified for to use simplePing. It was creating a memory leak. I switched to this library found [here](http://elbsolutions.com/projects/reachability-with-simpleping-wrapper/)

Good luck and I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: Did you find any solution other than the SimplePinger?

Comment: SimplePing was the best solution thus far.

Comment: I know but it seems that C api that SimplePing uses won't work with GCD. I report it to Apple and they asked me to send them a project that reproduce the error. The didn't come back yet